# How do I check framerate in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How would I check the framerate in my javascript code? I'm using this to loop:

```
gameloopId = setInterval(gameLoop, 10);
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In `gameLoop`, look at the difference between `new Date` and `new Date` from the last loop (store it in a variable).
In other words:

```
var lastLoop = new Date();
function gameLoop() { 
    var thisLoop = new Date();
    var fps = 1000 / (thisLoop - lastLoop);
    lastLoop = thisLoop;
    ...
}
```

`thisLoop - lastLoop` is the number of milliseconds that passed between the two loops.

Comment: could your replace new Date by Date.now(), same thing, but more correct imo

Comment: How to refresh the function gameLoop() depending on actual fps? Because when using setInterval() I can pass the argument of time interval only once.

Comment: @JacekDziurdzikowski: Call `setTimeout()` each time to schedule the next frame.

Comment: @JacekDziurdzikowski Using `requestAnimationFrame` is better for performance than using either `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` since it automatically adjusts the timing to the fps.

Comment: If it were up to me, I'd prefer using something like performance.now instead of dates because of its advantages in accuracy and efficiency

Answer (score 116):

The code by @Slaks gives you only the instantaneous FPS of the last frame, which may vary or be misleading with hiccups. I prefer to use an easy-to-write-and-compute low-pass filter to remove quick transients and display a reasonable pseudo-average of recent results:

```
// The higher this value, the less the fps will reflect temporary variations
// A value of 1 will only keep the last value
var filterStrength = 20;
var frameTime = 0, lastLoop = new Date, thisLoop;

function gameLoop(){
  // ...
  var thisFrameTime = (thisLoop=new Date) - lastLoop;
  frameTime+= (thisFrameTime - frameTime) / filterStrength;
  lastLoop = thisLoop;
}

// Report the fps only every second, to only lightly affect measurements
var fpsOut = document.getElementById('fps');
setInterval(function(){
  fpsOut.innerHTML = (1000/frameTime).toFixed(1) + " fps";
},1000);
```

The 'halflife' of this filter—the number of frames needed to move halfway from the old value to a new, stable value—is `filterStrength*Math.log(2)` (roughly 70% of the strength).

For example, a strength of `20` will move halfway to an instantaneous change in 14 frames, 3/4 of the way there in 28 frames, 90% of the way there in 46 frames, and 99% of the way there in 92 frames. For a system running at about 30fps, a sudden, drastic shift in performance will be obvious in half a second, but will still 'throw away' single-frame anomalies as they will only shift the value by 5% of the difference.

Here is a visual comparison of different filter strengths for a ~30fps game that has a momentary dip to 10fps and then later speeds up to 50fps. As you can see, lower filter values more quickly reflect 'good' changes, but also are more susceptible to temporary hiccups:
[image]

Finally, here is [an example](http://phrogz.net/tmp/image_move_sprites_canvas.html) of using the above code to actually benchmark a 'game' loop.

Comment: Very nice graphic! How did you do that?

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer The above was created in Excel, only because it was slightly easier for a one-off than [using HTML5 Canvas for pretty IIR graphing](http://phrogz.net/js/framerate-independent-low-pass-filter.html).

Comment: Is there any reason why I'm getting infinite fps when using request animation frame. I'm using a filter strength of 1 for the most accurate fps? only happens from time to time (Infinite fps) : http://jsfiddle.net/CezarisLT/JDdjp/10/

Comment: @CezarisLT Infinite FPS == one callback reporting the same time (`new Date`) as the previous call. You can guard for this by bailing `if (thisLoop==lastLoop)`. However, note that if you're using a filter strength of `1`, there's no point in using the filter at all. Just use @SLaks answer.

Comment: @Phrogz I know i am a bit late to the party.. but even when i use your suggested guard agains the infinite fps bug. i still get infinite fps? any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

My 2 cents:

Useful to me to compare optimizations.
Burn a bit of resources, of course, for testing only.

Ideally, your app frame rate should always stay well under 50ms by frame, at full usage, when using events, loops, etc. This is equal to 20FPS.

The Human eye feels lags under 24 FPS, this is **1000 / 24 = 41ms**

So, **41ms** for a frame is the smallest time window, to maintain natural fluidity. Higher than that is to be avoided.

```js
let be = Date.now(),fps=0,info='';
requestAnimationFrame(
    function loop(){
        let now = Date.now()
        fps = Math.round(1000 / (now - be))
        be = now
        requestAnimationFrame(loop)
        if (fps < 35){
          kFps.style.color = "red"
          kFps.textContent = fps 
        } if (fps >= 35 && fps <= 41) {
            kFps.style.color = "deepskyblue"
            kFps.textContent = fps + " FPS"
          } else {
            kFps.style.color = "black"
            kFps.textContent = fps + " FPS"
        }
        kpFps.value = fps;
        info+=(''+new Date()+' '+fps+'\n');
    }
 )
```

```html
<span id="kFps"></span>
<progress id="kpFps" value="0" min="0" max="100" style="vertical-align:middle"></progress>
<button onclick="try{console.clear();console.info(info)}catch{}">Statistics</button>
```

---

Just a test loop to get the idea, 50ms interval, should keep up smooth!

See the progress bar above jumping? ^

Those are frames losses, the browser is trying to keep up by sacrifice, by jumping to the next frame. Those spikes are to be avoided.
The next snippet burns resources (i.e FPS):

```js
let t
for (let i=0;i<99999;i++){
  t = setTimeout(function(){
   console.log("I am burning your CPU! " + i)
   clearTimeout(t)
  },50)
  
}
```

---

Recent versions of debuggers, have a FPS counter, in the `performance` tab, when recording. This is not perfect because it overload the testing.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

What about [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame)?

```
var before,now,fps;
before=Date.now();
fps=0;
requestAnimationFrame(
    function loop(){
        now=Date.now();
        fps=Math.round(1000/(now-before));
        before=now;
        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        console.log("fps",fps)
    }
 );
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this to calculate fps

```
  var GameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
  var GameContext = doContext(GameCanvas,"GameCanvas");
  var FPS = 0;
  var TimeNow;
  var TimeTaken;
  var ASecond = 1000;
  var FPSLimit = 25;
  var StartTime = Date.now();
  var TimeBefore = StartTime;
  var FrameTime = ASecond/FPSLimit;
  var State = { Title:0, Started:1, Paused:2, Over:3 };
  var GameState = State.Title;

  function gameLoop() {
    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
    TimeNow = Date.now();
    TimeTaken = TimeNow - TimeBefore;

    if (TimeTaken >= FrameTime) {
      FPS++
      if((TimeNow - StartTime) >= ASecond){
        StartTime += ASecond;
        doFPS();
        FPS = 0;
      }

      switch(GameState){
        case State.Title :
          break;
        case State.Started :
          break;
        case State.Paused :
          break;
        case State.Over :
          break;
      }
      TimeBefore = TimeNow - (TimeTaken % FrameTime);
    }
  }

  Sprites.onload = function(){
    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
  }

  function drawText(Context,_Color, _X, _Y, _Text, _Size){
    Context.font =  "italic "+ _Size +" bold";
    Context.fillStyle = _Color;
    Context.fillText(_Text, _X, _Y);
  }

  function doFPS()(
    drawText(GameContext,"black",10,24,"FPS : " + FPS,"24px");
  }

  function doContext(Canvas,Name){
    if (Canvas.getContext) {
      var Context = Canvas.getContext('2d');
      return Context;
    }else{
      alert( Name + ' not supported your Browser needs updating');
    }
  }
```