# How to get CPU consumption rate of a website using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I know that sounds like a ridiculous question or maybe a few years ago it would have. I would like to know when my website is using the users CPU so I can display a notification (in the form of a box turning from red to green). This would be easy if the site only used JavaScript but it also uses CSS3 animations, video, and flash.

Comment: Chrome DevTools can do that: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/cpu-profiling

Comment: I mean through JavaScript.

Comment: +1 for DevTools, also see this: [Javascript- Dynamically monitor CPU/memory usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530680/javascript-dynamically-monitor-cpu-memory-usage).