# HTML 5 local computer hardware specs

Tags: jquery, html, hardware, cpu, specifications

Is there a way to use HTML 5 to access local system hardware details?

I'm looking specifically for attributes about CPU, RAM, Disk space, Video card information, Browsers available and plug-ins (with verson information).

Ultimately, I am trying to determine if I can build a tool to check a machine for hardware requirements to run software but do so without needing to actually install anything on the machine.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31775686/1026

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if HTML5 can help you but javascript can, more information on these websites.

http://ajaxian.com/archives/jpu-javascript-cpu-monitor

http://webreflection.blogspot.in/2007/09/jpu-javascript-cpu-monitor.html

[Get CPU/GPU/memory information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464896/javascript-get-cpu-gpu-memory-information)

[Javascript- Dynamically monitor CPU/memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530680/javascript-dynamically-monitor-cpu-memory-usage)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.msdos.batch.nt/1s8_OJ0WFaY

Answer (score 1):

no it's not possible.
the browser can't get these informations

the only way for CPU is if you make a benchmark, with a lot of data and the time you can guess the CPU