# How can I get CPU load each second in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP script:

```
$loads = sys_getloadavg();
$core_nums = trim(shell_exec("grep -P '^processor' /proc/cpuinfo|wc -l"));
$load = round($loads[0]/($core_nums)*100, 10);
```

I running this script each second using AJAX and setInterval for building CPU Load chart. But result of this PHP script updates only after 3 or more calls:

[image: cpu graph]

How can I get new data each second???

Comment: ajax is slow. every ajax request is a full-blown http roundtrip to/from the server. You'd be better off using a websocket and PUSHING per-second data to your client.

Comment: You could probably reduce the load on the CPU by 50% by not looking at the CPU load

Comment: No! Problem isn't from AJAX. I can reflesh the page with this PHP and I will still get the same result.

Comment: Have you considered a real monitoring tool, such as statsd with system info collection (like DataDog does)?

Comment: You may consider checking this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18152413/6381711).