# How can you do a heavy gpu test only using HTML? Like a real hard stress test for your device?

Tags: html

I was wondering how can you do a crazy hard gpu stress test using only HTML

I tried a stress test by getting my device to make 510K random points using complex math but that did not really work... But I do  thing that photon mapping would be the best option.

Comment: See this that may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/54747975/2494754

Comment: TL;DR: HTML is not the right tool to perform a "*crazy hard gpu stress test*". What would you consider as "*only HTML*"? "*I tried a stress test by getting my device to make 510K random points using complex math*" I am curious if what you describe here was "*using only HTML*", but I would surmise the answer to be "no" since this the scaffolding that would be required to even codify this level of logic is simply not present in any current HTML spec. "*but that did not really work*" Didn't work *how*? What *specifically* didn't meet your requirements?